# Way to get installation date of python package of a virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, package

I am looking for some way to get installation date of python package in a virtualenv, **but without using a python script**. I don't know if there are any tool like `freeze` that give me this info (at least).

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

we can do this with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), [pip show](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/#pip-show)  and with time

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

package_name = 'requests'

package_param = subprocess.check_output(
            ['pip', 'show', package_name], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
# subprocess will return a string of type `bytes` with 
# name, version, location, and we need to get Location, like so:

# Name: requests
# Version: 1.4.5
# another params
# Location: /my/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

# here we decode pack, because this is a bytes, and spltit by '\n'
# go through this list of strings and check if we have `Location` in string
# if we have location we get this location and with `oc.path.getctime()`
# get the time when this package was created
for param in package_param.decode().split('\n'):
    if 'Location' in param:
        loc = param.split(':')[1].strip()
        print("{}: {}".format(package_name, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(loc))))
```

**Output**

```
requests: Fri Jun 15 10:03:50 2018
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution without a python script, (at least for now).

Comment: oh sorry i don't see that, but if you will need it this script works

Comment: This is very nice, but it would have been great to do for all installed packages. Is there a simple way to retrieve all installed packages from within python? (For example, this would have been straight forward if your script would accept a bash pipe with the list. )

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve the same is by checking for package directory modification date inside **site-packages**.

If you are using **linux environment** then you can run following commands:

To check **active python environment** directory

```
$ which python
```

**Sample Output:** `/[path-to-virtualenv]/bin/python`

To **list all the packages** with **formatted date**

```
$ cd /[path-to-virtualenv]/lib/python-[version-number]/site-packages
$ ls -al --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d"
```

**Sample Output:** `drwxrwxr-x 19 [user] [user]   [file size] [YEAR-MONTH-DATE] [package name]`

To filter package with **specific date** you can use **grep**:

```
$ ls -al --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d" | grep '2021-03-14'
```

**Expected Output:** It will list all the directories/files which get modified on 2020-03-14